# How to select laptop screen without actually seeing the screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr, external-monitor

This is a weird situation on a Lubuntu 16.04 (which, no, it does not automatically recognize the active monitor, like Ubuntu), where the HDMI monitor alone was selected to give a presentation, the screen preferences were saved, and the HDMI was disconnected afterwards without restoring to LCD laptop again. Now, when the computer is started and you log into the same user, the screen remains blank. Launching a terminal (Ctrl-T) and typing commands like `xrand -auto` (which I think is the right one) did not solved the situation.

Note: I can't access any other account to administer the system (only guest is available).

Update: `xrand --output LVDS-1`, which works in another laptop, did not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Likely that LVDS is not correct magic word for this particular computer. Otherwise, your attack is clever.

I fear only fix is restart. Most graceful AltCtl-F1, login, then

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

After restart, run

```
xrandr --query
```

To see what magic is needed instead of LVDS. Be aware these can change when video drivers update.